# How to export from sql to a formatted excel

Tags: c#, wpf, export-to-excel

I have a C# WPF application which interacts with SQL Server Database. In application I want user be able to export some kind of data from SQL to Excel. I'm trying firstly to fill a Datatable and then export it to excel file. Everything was fine, untill I faced up with a task to export a datatable filled with this sql query:[image]

to a formatted excel file like this:
[image: report]

So how can I sort selldetails of every sell in one region in excel file?
It's been a long time I'm puzzling my mind over this problem, please, help me!

Comment: hi PLease have a look on this  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20228/Using-C-to-Create-an-Excel-Document

Comment: thanks for the link, but it's not what I want. I want to group same IDs in Excel file, so that all related to id selldetails are placed in one region.

Comment: Yes that you have to do programatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case if someone needs to solve a problem in analogy I achieved the goal with this piece of code:

```
        int currentXLLine = 1; // line in xls file to start
        int currentId = -1;    // current sellID  
        int detailCount = 1;
        int beginSumLine = currentXLLine+3;
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            if ((currentId != (int)dt.Rows[i][0])) 
            {

                if (i != 0)
                {
                    cell = oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine+1, 7];
                    cell.Font.Bold = true;
                    cell.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlRight;
                    cell.Value = "OVERALL:";
                    cell = oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine + 1, 8];
                    cell.Formula = "=SUM(H"+beginSumLine.ToString()+":H" + currentXLLine.ToString() + ")";
                    cell.Font.Bold = true;
                    cell.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlRight;

                    cell = oSheet.Columns[7];
                    Past.AutoFitColumn(oSheet, 7);
                    cell.NumberFormat = "# ##0.00";
                    cell = oSheet.Columns[8];
                    Past.AutoFitColumn(oSheet, 8);
                    cell.NumberFormat = "# ##0.00";
                    cell.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;

                    currentXLLine += 3;
                    detailCount = 1;

                }

                oRange = oSheet.get_Range("B" + currentXLLine.ToString(), "C" + currentXLLine.ToString());
                oRange.Merge(Type.Missing);
                oRange.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
                oRange.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlRight;
                oRange.VerticalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = false;
                oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 2] = "SellDate";

                oRange = oSheet.get_Range("D" + currentXLLine.ToString(), "E" + currentXLLine.ToString());
                oRange.Merge(Type.Missing);
                oRange.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
                oRange.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlLeft;
                oRange.VerticalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = false;
                oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 4] = dt.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                beginSumLine = currentXLLine + 3;

                currentXLLine += 2;


                oRange = oSheet.get_Range("C" + currentXLLine.ToString(), "E" + currentXLLine.ToString());
                oRange.Merge(Type.Missing);
                oRange.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
                oRange.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.VerticalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

                oRange = oSheet.get_Range("B" + currentXLLine.ToString(), "B" + currentXLLine.ToString());
                oRange.Merge(Type.Missing);
                oRange.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
                oRange.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.VerticalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

                oRange = oSheet.get_Range("F" + currentXLLine.ToString(), "F" + currentXLLine.ToString());
                oRange.Merge(Type.Missing);
                oRange.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
                oRange.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.VerticalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

                oRange = oSheet.get_Range("G" + currentXLLine.ToString(), "G" + currentXLLine.ToString());
                oRange.Merge(Type.Missing);
                oRange.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
                oRange.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.VerticalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

                oRange = oSheet.get_Range("H" + currentXLLine.ToString(), "H" + currentXLLine.ToString());
                oRange.Merge(Type.Missing);
                oRange.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
                oRange.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.VerticalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlCenter;
                oRange.EntireRow.Font.Bold = true;

                oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 2] = "№";
                oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 3] = "ProductName";
                oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 6] = "Quantity";
                oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 7] = "Price";
                oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 8] = "Sum";
                currentXLLine += 1;

            }

        oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 2] = (detailCount).ToString(); //rowView.Row["Ассортимент"].ToString();
        cell = oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 2];
        cell.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);

        oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 3] = (string)dt.Rows[i][4];
        cell = oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 3];
        cell.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
        oRange = oSheet.get_Range("C" + (currentXLLine).ToString(), "E" + (currentXLLine).ToString());
        oRange.Merge(Type.Missing);
        oRange.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
        oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 6] = dt.Rows[i][5].ToString();
        cell = oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 6];
        cell.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
        oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 7] = dt.Rows[i][6].ToString();
        cell = oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 7];
        cell.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
        oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 8] = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i][5])*Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][6]);
        cell = oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine, 8];
        cell.BorderAround(ExcelApp.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous, ExcelApp.XlBorderWeight.xlThin, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlColorIndex.xlColorIndexAutomatic, Missing.Value);
        detailCount += 1;
        currentXLLine += 1;
        currentId = (int)dt.Rows[i][0];

    }


cell = oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine + 1, 7];
  cell.Font.Bold = true;
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlRight;
  cell.Value = "OVERALL:";
  cell = oSheet.Cells[currentXLLine + 1, 8];
  cell.Formula = "=SUM(H" + beginSumLine.ToString() + ":H" + currentXLLine.ToString() + ")";
  cell.Font.Bold = true;
  cell.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelApp.Constants.xlRight;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an excel interop.Excel Interop allows formatting a particular range or even a particular cell...

This links may help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/137183/Tip-Format-an-Excel-Range-as-a-Table-Programatical